# create tensorflow dataset from list_files

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create tensroflow dataset :

```
path_imgs = ('./images/train/*.jpg')
path_masks =('./masks/train/*.jpg'

images = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path_imgs, shuffle=False)
masks = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path_masks, shuffle=False)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(path_imgs),
                                              tf.constant(path_masks)))
```

and I am receiving:

`Unbatching a tensor is only supported for rank >= 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

path_imgs = ('/content/images/*.jpg')
path_masks = ('/content/masks/*.jpg')

images = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path_imgs, shuffle=False)
masks = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path_masks, shuffle=False)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((images, masks))

def load_data(image_path, mask_path):
  return tf.image.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(image_path)), tf.image.decode_image(tf.io.read_file(mask_path))

ds = ds.map(load_data)

for x, y in ds:
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

```
(100, 100, 3) (100, 100, 3)
(100, 100, 3) (100, 100, 3)
```

Note, however, what the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files) state regarding `tf.data.Dataset.list_files`:

> The file_pattern argument should be a small number of glob patterns. If your filenames have already been globbed, use Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames) instead, as re-globbing every filename with list_files may result in poor performance with remote storage systems.

Splitting also works:

```
train_ds, test_ds = tf.keras.utils.split_dataset(ds, left_size=0.5, right_size=0.5, shuffle=True, seed=123)
```

Here is the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pZxeV3YxM7V4b5l7sXbxi8lvdUgLlPt_?usp=sharing) to try it out.

Comment: Hmm.If I try to do 
    `train_ds, test_ds = tf.keras.utils.split_dataset(
        dataset,
        left_size=0.8,
        right_size=0.2,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=123)` . I am receving: `Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor).`

Comment: I am using this dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/franciscoescobar/satellite-images-of-water-bodies

Comment: Yes, I am using your example.  the type is `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset` and dataset shows: `<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.uint8, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.uint8, name=None))>`

Comment: Hmm I cannot reproduce your error... It is working without any problems on Google Colab with TF 2.10.0.  Should I share the notebook?

Comment: No, it's ok. I will search it. Thank you very much.